# Angular Change RouteLink by other component and add additional queryparam

Tags: angular

Current link like

```
http://.../test/0?params=0
http://.../test/1?params=1
...
http://.../test/10?params=10
```

I want replace `test` to `other-test` and keep the queryParams, then add another queryParams `form=1` like this.

`http://..../other-test/?form=1&params={{i}}`

I concat the string but it escaped to `%3F and %3D`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-unescapse

html

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of arr">
        <a routerLink="{{defaultLink}}/{{item.link}}" [queryParams]="{params: item.link}">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<button (click)="otherComponentChangeLink()">Click it </button>
```

ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  defaultLink = 'test';

  arr = Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => ({name: `NavLink item ${i}`, link: i}));

  otherComponentChangeLink() {
    const additionalParams = 'form=1'
    this.defaultLink = 'other-test/' + '?' + additionalParams;
    // change link like this
    // http://..../other-test/?form=1&params={{i}}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **It is called URL Encoding**

By default, Angular encodes every URL, using its default [`URLSerializer`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer)

In order to prevent Angular from encoding certain characters in your URL (in your case it `=` and `?`), you need to write your **Custom URL Serailizer**.

In your case it will be like this:

**custom-url-serializer.ts**

```
import {UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer} from '@angular/router';

export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    parse(url: any): UrlTree {
        let dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
        return dus.parse(url);
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
        let defaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer(),
            defaultPath = defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree);
        // Here I've replace %3F with ? and %3D with = to stop URL encoding for these characters
        return defaultPath.replace(/%3F/g, '?').replace(/%3D/g, '=');
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { CustomUrlSerializer } from'./custom-url-serializer'
import {UrlSerializer} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,  RouterModule.forRoot([]) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [{ provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer }] // <- add this line
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-unescapse-hwgpf2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That was a really good answer. But is it possible to make a directive to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using property-binding instead of interpolation like:

```
<a [routerLink]="defaultLink+'/'+item.link" [queryParams]="{params: item.link}">{{item.name}}</a>
```

And you should not be adding queryParams using string manipulation like you're doing in otherComponentChangeLink(), that's why you're getting escape sequence %3F and %3D in the link.

Comment: It's easy to do this in current component. I don't know how to change the link in another component, and keep current param and add another queryParam.

Comment: hey, you can do this in current component

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Router package for this.

Add a Constructor which handles the routes.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      //Store params here
    }); 
}
```

in otherComponentChangeLink:

```
this.router.navigate(["http://..../other-test?form=1"], { queryParams: { param1: "storedParams" } })
```

Then you can rebuild the link with navigate, or use navigateByUrl

[Angular docs Router](https://angular.io/guide/router)
[NavigateByUrl](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-routerlink-navigate-navigatebyurl/)

Comment: This can be used in navigation and @wgf4242 wants to chage urls with click of button and not navigate.